# How to join results of multiple select statements ina query that involves update statements

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have a table that has the columns Y, X1, X2 and W. I am doing for each column

```
declare @std float
set @std = (select SUM(W*Col) from table)
update table set Col=sqrt(W)*(Col-@std)
select @std
```

How can i efficiently combine these queries for each column and return 3 values [@std for each column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows your definitions, although updating a column based on its own value is a bit odd. I hope you're only planning to run this query once.

```
DECLARE
    @std_y  FLOAT,
    @std_x1 FLOAT,
    @std_x2 FLOAT

SELECT
    @std_y =  SUM(W*Y),
    @std_x1 = SUM(W*X1),
    @std_x2 = SUM(W*X2)
FROM
    dbo.My_Table

UPDATE dbo.My_Table
SET
    Y  = SQRT(W) * (Y  - @std_y),
    X1 = SQRT(W) * (X1 - @std_y),
    X2 = SQRT(W) * (X2 - @std_y)

SELECT
    @std_y  AS std_y,
    @std_x1 AS std_x1,
    @std_x2 AS std_x2
```